# How to iterate over 2 equal size ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I'm creating a GUI memory game, and I have an arraylist with 30 imageicons(in a specific image class) and one with 30 jbuttons(in the jframe class). I'd like to iterate through them and add the first imageicon to the first jbutton and so on.

```
private static ArrayList<JButton> btnList = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<ImageIcon> animalArrayList = Images.initAnimalArrayList();
```

I'm unfamiliar with Collection.iterator and am having a hard time figuring out what I need to do to set it up.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you can learn a little and get a lot from http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays

Comment: why not just do a standard for loop and use list.get(i)

Comment: @chatton. I was thinking about that, using the index is helpful(I have a get method in my image class that uses.get()), but I cant see how I would use the index to also call setIcon() on my jbuttons which are called "btn1, btn2,..."

Comment: @cobes `but I cant see how I would use the index to also call setIcon() on my jbuttons which are called "btn1, btn2,..."` I don't understand you already have an ArrayList called "btnList" so what is that for?

Comment: Nevermind... I'm dense

Answer (score 0):

My proposed answer below:

```
int size = btnList.size();
for (int i =0; i < size; i++){
    btnList.get(i).setIcon(animalArrayList.get(i));
}
```

To understand Iterator:

Iterator allow you  cycle through a collection similar to a for loop for e.g.:

```
Iterator itr = btnList.iterator();
while itr.hasNext(){ // while we have not loop through all elements
    //get object 
    JButton btn = itr.next()
    //do additional action
}
```

The for loop allows you to access the same index location for the btnList array list and the animalArrayList getting the required  output.

The reason why size is equal to btnList.size() is because I assumed that the same number of buttons and images would have to exist. therefore this accommodates any array-list size.